# Trying to programmatically get ngrok process https address for node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ngrok

I'm running ngrok process to tunnel to a port that a node.js server is listening to, and I want to know if it is possible to grab this https address, using code. I am using the free version of ngrok and this produces a unique random prefix for the ngrok.io address assignment.

So ultimately I want it to recover, restart ngrok process on port XXXX, if the server had an unexpected reboot, pull this address it generates, and keep that new address for further function or even to notify "Back Home" of the new address that is reassigned.

I know there are great options on ngrok that I will be exploring, especially the paid business ones, just was curious if what I'm asking is possible or not. I know anything is possible, if you delve in deep, but I guess what I'm asking is if the capabilities are setup for easy access, so to speak.

I suspect this link below has a lead to what I want... might be about parsing at this point

http://127.0.0.1:4040/inspect/http

Comment: Ngrok is mostly intended to building and testing webhooks rather than acting as a production-like tunnel service. It sounds like you probably need something a bit more robust. If all you're after is parsing the ngrok output then you'll want to pass ngrok -log=stdout which could then be parsed depending on your system.

Comment: I have not been able to find the ngrok generated URL in this log output. Do you know if there's a way to get it? I also posted this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921092/how-to-get-programmatically-get-ngroks-urls.